# runing each function to find elements having a matching class jquery

Tags: jquery

I have certain elements in a form having id 'searchForm'. I need to find all elements whose class ends in "fromDate" so that i can perform some operation like validation on it.

Here is a sample element

```
<input type="text" class="FRANCHISEE_openingDatefromDate" name="FRANCHISEE_openingDateFrom" size="17">
<script>
    $('[class^=fromDate]').each(function(index, value){
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    </script>
```

And i want something like this:-
But its not getting inside each loop, can somebody point out whats the mistake or please provide correct approach/solution.

Comment: `^=` means 'starts with'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$=` condition:

```
$("#searchForm [class$='fromDate']")
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: Thanks @curt ... can i check it within a form instead of whole DOM form has id='searchForm'

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Attribute Ends With Selector [name$="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
$('[class$="fromDate"]').each(function(index, value){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("put your certain element").each(function(){
   var currentId=$(this).attr("id");
   if( currentId.indexOf('fromDate') >= 0){
   // perform action to $(this) element
   }
});
```